# Retrofit2, converter-simplexml - помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой

Tags: android, retrofit, rss, simplexml

Есть новосной сайт: http://www.cbc.ca/cmlink/rss-topstories/ с RSS лентой. Немогу исправить ошибку.

```
08-15 16:44:35.574 12199-12199/com.ku4irka.rss_nfr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.ku4irka.rss_nfr, PID: 12199
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ku4irka.rss_nfr/com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.view.activity.ListNewsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.model.entity.Channel>
                                                                     for method ChannelService.getChannel
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5698)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.model.entity.Channel>
                                                                     for method ChannelService.getChannel
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:706)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:167)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
                                                                     at $Proxy0.getChannel(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.view.activity.ListNewsActivity.configRest(ListNewsActivity.java:48)
                                                                     at com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.view.activity.ListNewsActivity.onCreate(ListNewsActivity.java:36)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                        ... 10 more
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for java.util.List<com.ku4irka.rss_nfr.model.entity.Channel>.
                                                                   Tried:
                                                                    * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
                                                                    * retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:346)
                                                                     at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:308)
                                                                     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:704)
                                                                        ... 20 more
```

Пример кода:

```
public class RestManager {

private static final OkHttpClient CLIENT = new OkHttpClient();

private static Retrofit retrofit;

private static ChannelService sChannelService;

private static void retrofitSetup() {
    // Retrofit setup
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constans.HTTP.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .client(CLIENT)
            .build();
}




public static ChannelService getChannelService() {
    if (sChannelService == null) {

        retrofitSetup();
        // Service setup
        sChannelService = retrofit.create(ChannelService.class);
    }
    return sChannelService;
}
}





public interface ChannelService {

@GET("cmlink/rss-topstories/")
Call<List<Channel>> getChannel();
}



@Root(name = "channel")
public class Channel {

@Element(name = "guid")
private double id;

@Element(name = "title")
private String title;

@Element(name = "pubDate")
private String pubDate;

@Element(name = "author")
private String author;

@Element(name = "description")
private String description;

@Element(name = "link")
private String link;

public Channel() {
}

public double getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(double id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
}



private void configRest() {
    Call<List<Channel>> call = mRestManager.getChannelService().getChannel();

    // Asynchronously execute HTTP request
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Channel>>() {
        /**
         * onResponse is called when any kind of response has been received.
         */
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Channel>> call, Response<List<Channel>> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                mNewsList = response.body();
                setRecyclerView();
            } else {
                int sc = response.code();
                switch (sc) {
                    case 400:
                        Toast.makeText(ListNewsActivity.this, "'Error 400' Bad Request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        Toast.makeText(ListNewsActivity.this, "'Error 404' Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(ListNewsActivity.this, "'Error' Generic Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Channel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(ListNewsActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем же проблема ?

Comment: У вас Call<List<Channel>> getChannel();, но Channel - корневой элемент и он только один. Попробуйте так Call<Channel> getChannel();

Comment: Спасибо! пробовал, кажется ето не в етом проблема.. Сервис должен возвращать List обектов..